# Pie/pic elf binary instrumentation

Tags: reverse-engineering, elf, aslr

Let’s suppose i have an elf 32 or 64 bits binary executable. This binary has been compiled with pic/pie options.

That’s mean all functions are mapped at a random address in memory.

What should i do if à need to make instrumentation or reverse engineering on this kind of binary ?

Is there a way to hook linux binary loader in order to always give the same addresses ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That’s mean all functions are mapped at a random address in memory.

No, it *doesn't* mean that.

With address randomization enabled, the PIE binary will be loaded at a random base address from run to run, but *all* functions and data will move *together*.

That is, if `&foo == 0x12345600` and `&bar == 0x12345700` in one execution, then the delta between them will always be `0x100` in subsequent executions (until the binary is relinked).

> Is there a way to hook linux binary loader in order to always give the same addresses ?

There are several ways:

- Address randomization can be globally disabled via
   `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`
- Use `setarch ... -R a.out`
- Run the program under GDB, which disables randomization via [personality](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html) system call.